# c# selenium + phantomjs upload image

Tags: c#, file-upload, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, image-uploading

I'm trying to upload a image in a website using phantomjs and selenium with c#. That's the code of the input file.

```
<div id="wrapper_image_upload_button" class="wrapper_image_upload_button main_picture">
    <div class="title">
        <label class="ipt_label">Foto Principal</label>
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <span id="image_upload_button" class="image_upload_button" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden; direction: ltr;">adicionar imagens
        <input multiple="multiple" accept="image/*" type="file" name="file" style="height: 72px; position: absolute; right: 0px; top: 0px; font-family: Arial; font-size: 118px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; cursor: pointer; opacity: 0;"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Or its in fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ob3dxoz7/

I tried:

```
var add_img = driver.FindElement(By.Id("image_upload_button"));
var imagem = add_img.FindElement(By.Name("file"));


Console.WriteLine(imagem.GetAttribute("type"));//output : file
string filepath = "C://cow.jpg";

imagem.SendKeys(filepath);
```

Error throws in :

```
imagem.SendKeys(filepath);
```

Error:
    An unhandled exception of type 'OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException' occurred in WebDriver.dll

Additional information: The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL localhost value timed out after 60 seconds.

How can I upload the image?

Comment: Ok. I edited and wrote the full error.

Comment: At what point in the execution is the errror thrown? Also, where is the call to `add_img.Click()`?

Comment: The error throw in imagem.SendKeys(filepath);

Comment: Ok. Is there other code after that call? Because you're not actually uploading the file, you still need to click the button...

Comment: There is just the code for click in the submit button in this form. This button works fine without uploading this image.But I need to upload it